# Configuration for SSL redirect on Heroku causing error 403 (Forbidden) when accessing root domain

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, heroku, http-status-code-403

I have a PHP website that was working properly, hosted on Heroku (apache). I have just configured SSL and I would like to force users using https. Then I've found some instructions to do that on Heroku, using 'Procfile' approach, a file where I can indicate a new file so-called "apache_app.conf" with mod_rewrite directives and execute what I need.

Code for Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C apache_app.conf /
```

You can see the code for the file apache_app.conf below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This code worked fine, in respect of redirect funcionality, but the problem is that I am receiving the following message when I am accessing the root domain (https://example.com):

## Forbidden

## You don't have permission to access / on this server.

When I explicitly type "https://example.com/index.php", it works fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use htacess for redirection as Procfile is to refer starting point of application

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That is the code for apache_app.conf. I will reformulate the question. I used the Procfile to indicate that apache_app.conf file would be read as a extension to htacess. By the way, is there a way I can edit htacess on heroku? I thought that it is only possible adding directives to apache_app.conf.

Answer (score 0):

As per heroku it doesn't allow the default file to be executed from root, please move index.php to folder like app and update your Procfile as below

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 app/ -C apache_app.conf
```

Comment: I am new on apache/php. The problem was that I had tried executing mod_rewrite directives on apache_app.conf file. Later on, I realized that running the same commands on .htaccess file, on the root of my website, it worked fine. I do not know why the same directives have different behavior on these 2 contexts, but now it is working properly.